What is this meaning of たり得る?
"愛していることがどうして本質たり得る?"
"俺は、だからこそ行動した。それが全ての起点だ"
The character is a robot and I guess he wants to know how "to love" can be the 本質 of a person.
But I don't understand what たり得る is doing?

～たり is just an old fashioned way to say ～だ. たり得る is the combination of たり and 得る, which is a verb meaning ことができる. So, 本質たり得る corresponds to 本質であることができる in modern Japanese.
